# What's the SQL national character (NCHAR) datatype really for?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, nvarchar

As well as `CHAR` `(CHARACTER)` and `VARCHAR` `(CHARACTER VARYING)`, SQL offers an `NCHAR` `(NATIONAL CHARACTER)` and `NVARCHAR` `(NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING)` type. In some databases, this is the better datatype to use for character (non-binary) strings:

- In SQL Server, `NCHAR` is stored as UTF-16LE and is the only way to reliably store non-ASCII characters, `CHAR` being a single-byte codepage only;
- In Oracle, `NVARCHAR` may be stored as UTF-16 or UTF-8 rather than a single-byte collation;
- But in MySQL, `NVARCHAR` is `VARCHAR`, so it makes no difference, either type can be stored with UTF-8 or any other collation.

So, what does `NATIONAL` actually conceptually mean, if anything? The vendors' docs only tell you about what character sets their own DBMSs use, rather than the actual rationale. Meanwhile the SQL92 standard explains the feature even less helpfully, stating only that `NATIONAL CHARACTER` is stored in an implementation-defined character set. As opposed to a mere `CHARACTER`, which is stored in an implementation-defined character set. Which might be a different implementation-defined character set. Or not.

Thanks, ANSI. Thansi.

Should one use `NVARCHAR` for all character (non-binary) storage purposes? Are there currently-popular DBMSs in which it will do something undesirable, or which just don't recognise the keyword (or `N''` literals)?

Comment: SQL Server stores NVARCHAR in UCS-2 encoding, not in UTF-16: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962%28SQL.90%29.aspx#intlftrql2005_topic2

Comment: @bobince, What does "Thansi" mean?

Answer (score 17):

"NATIONAL" in this case means characters specific to different nationalities.  Far east languages especially have so many characters that one byte is not enough space to distinguish them all.  So if you have an english(ascii)-only app *or an english-only field*, you can get away using the older CHAR and VARCHAR types, which only allow one byte per character.

That said, most of the time you should use NCHAR/NVARCHAR.  Even if you don't think you need to support (or potentially support) multiple languages in your data, even english-only apps need to be able to sensibly handle security attacks using foreign-language characters.

In my opinion, about the only place where the older CHAR/VARCHAR types are still preferred is for frequently-referenced ascii-only internal codes and data on platforms like Sql Server that support the distinction — data that would be the equivalent of an `enum` in a client language like C++ or C#.

Comment: I'll disagree. There are massive performance implication of using nvarchar in SQL Server . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366/varchar-vs-nvarchar-performance/198753#198753 if you don't need it, don't use it...

Comment: There are definitely performance concerns. But I believe the correctness issues tend to trump them

Comment: Correctness would be using the datatype needed. ISO Currency codes for example would be char(3), no need to anything more.

Answer (score 5):

> Meanwhile the SQL92 standard explains
> the feature even less helpfully,
> stating only that NATIONAL CHARACTER
> is stored in an implementation-defined
> character set. As opposed to a mere
> CHARACTER, which is stored in an
> implementation-defined character set.
> Which might be a different
> implementation-defined character set.
> Or not.

Coincidentally, this is the same "distinction" the C++ standard makes between `char` and `wchar_t`.  A relic of the Dark Ages of Character Encoding when every language/OS combination has its own character set.

> Should one use NVARCHAR for all
> character (non-binary) storage
> purposes?

It is not important whether the declared type of your column is `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`.  But it is important to use *Unicode* (whether UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32) for all character storage purposes.

> Are there currently-popular DBMSs in
> which it will do something undesirable

Yes: In MS SQL Server, using `NCHAR` makes your (English) data take up twice as much space.  <s>Unfortunately, UTF-8 isn't supported yet.</s>

**EDIT**: SQL Server 2019 finally [introduced UTF-8 support](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928).

Comment: I was thinking of more unsupported-feature-undesirable or make-the-query-fail-undesirable than mere efficiency, but true enough I suppose! So can you say what the desired distinction between a `CHAR` and an `NCHAR` at the time during the Dark Ages it was proposed? As I understand it, ignoring the issue of how a `wchar_t` is stored in-memory, the whole point of `wchar_t` was to offer codepoint semantics (since then of course potentially UTF-16 code unit semantics), whereas `NCHAR` doesn't seem to inherently guarantee codepoint, code unit or byte semantics, just a ‘different somehow’ encoding.

Comment: It isn't about just storage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366/varchar-vs-nvarchar-performance/198753#198753

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, the database character set can be a multi-byte character set, so you can store all manner of characters in there....but you need to understand and define the length of the columns appropriately (in either BYTES or CHARACTERS).

NVARCHAR gives you the option to have a database character set that is a single-byte (which reduces the potential for confusion between BYTE or CHARACTER sized columns) and use NVARCHAR as the multi-byte. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch2charset.htm#i1007017).

Since I predominantly work with English data, I'd go with a multi-byte character set (UTF-8 mostly) as the database character set and ignore NVARCHAR. If I inherited an old database which was in a single-byte characterset and was too big to convert, I may use NVARCHAR. But I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Even if you're working with "English data" you normally still need to care about non-English characters.  People's names are a common example of non-English characters in an "English-speaking" system, but there are others.