# How significant is the performance difference when joining on nvarchar versus on int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I understand that join on nvarchar is slower because index is bigger as nvarchar using 2 bytes for each character but int is 4 bytes all the time. Is the join performance difference significant? Is there any strong reason to avoid join on nvarchar? I couldn't find any MSDN article about the topic.

Comment: I expect the performance difference to be negligible, but you should really try it out for your specific case.

Comment: @Sjoerd: over a few dozen rows, yes. Otherwise it *will* be huge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At least 8x CPU. This is the measurable increase in comparing nvarchar over varchar: unicode sorting and comparison rules are more complex that straight varchar.

- [What are the main performance differences between varchar and nvarchar SQL Server data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366/varchar-vs-nvarchar-performance/198753#198753)
- [SQL Server uses high CPU when searching inside nvarchar strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4717520/27535)

So, assuming varchar and int are equal (they aren't) nvarchar will have overhead compared to int

Then, byte for byte ('1234' vs 1234) you're comparing 10 bytes vs 4 bytes. This also means a wider key for less index and data entries per page = more IO.

Finally, if your nvarchar is more then 450 characters, you can't index it because index key is max 900 bytes wide.