# How to compare records in one table quickly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I have a project for literature researches with a table(in SQL Server 2014). I extract words from some books to comparison table. this table may have thousands of words.
I write a query to compare words in different documents and want to show them side by side to show that each word frequency in different book.
Write this:

```
SELECT c1.Word,c1.DocumentID,c1.WordCount,c2.DocumentID,c2.WordCount 
FROM dbo.Comparation c1 
JOIN dbo.Comparation c2 ON c2.Word = c1.Word AND c1.DocumentID <> c2.DocumentID
```

this query takes 15s on my machine. then i decided to show them page by page and write this:

```
SELECT c1.Word,c1.DocumentID,c1.WordCount,c2.DocumentID,c2.WordCount 
FROM dbo.Comparation c1 
JOIN dbo.Comparation c2 ON c2.Word = c1.Word AND c1.DocumentID <> c2.DocumentID 
ORDER BY c1.DocumentID OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY;
```

now for 15 or little more records speed of retrieve was good, but my problem is:
when offset is small, every things are OK but when i increase offset query runs slow.
Is there any way to load and compare these words fast?

Thank you.

With best regards.

[Comparison table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e52Ha.png)

Comment: Have you any indexes on that table? If not, create it, `create index ix_ Comparation__Word__DocumentID on Comparation (Word, DocumentID);`

Comment: This look like a one-time job - isn't 15s ok for it?

Comment: Dear  Evgeny, Thank you for your suggestion. I create that index, speed increased  a little. but still takes 4-5 seconds.

Comment: Dear  Ivan, this query used for an WinForms application. A researcher may compare lots of books any time! Thank you.

Comment: `c1.DocumentID <> c2.DocumentID` -> `c1.DocumentID > c2.DocumentID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are joining on the nvarchar column "Word". As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483805/how-significant-is-the-performance-difference-when-joining-on-nvarchar-versus-on) this has performance issues when used over a large number of rows.

Try maybe generating an extra "WordID" column which would be unique for each word and then joining on that.

Comment: Thank you dear ChrisS, i'll try it and tell you it's results. Thank you again.