# How can I select this in Microsoft Query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, microsoft-query

I have a stored procedure and a simple table.

I need to join this two object then allow user to see the result using `Microsoft Query` in Excel.

This is what I have. The `Exec SP_Budget` create global temp table and fill `##tmpBudget`

```
exec SP_Budget;
Select g.name, g.address,g.Amount,b.BudgetAmt from gTable g
Left join ##tmpBudget b on b.NameID=g.NameID
```

Microsoft query can only do a simple

```
select * from tTable
```

how can I do this?

I have to have the stored procedure because it does UNpivot inside the `SP_Budget`

EDIT:
The more I think about this. I think I need to post the original SP_Budget
so here it is. Because maybe a better approach is to create a function rather than SP_Budget. Here is my SP_Budget. Is it possible to convert this SP to a function?

```
--this link show me how to build column list for the PIVOT/UNPIVOT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585094/sql-server-pivots-displaying-row-values-to-column-headers
--this link show me how to build column list of a specific table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775409/unpivot-with-dynamic-columns-plus-column-names
--here we build the dynamic query for the column list for the PIVOT/UNPIVOT 
declare @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
select @cols = coalesce(@cols+N',', N'') + quotename(c.name) from syscolumns c
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'
where o.name = 'AcctHist' and c.name not in ('PID', 'UID') and c.name like 'ptdbal%' and  c.name <> 'PtdBal12' order by c.colid

--Construct the full T-SQL statement
--and execute dynamically
SET @sql = N'select 
DB,Acct,Sub,cpnyid
,Fiscyr+
CASE WHEN len(Convert(varchar(2),CONVERT(int,right(Period,2))+1))=1
THEN ''0''+Convert(varchar(2),CONVERT(int,right(Period,2))+1) 
ELSE Convert(varchar(2),CONVERT(int,right(Period,2))+1)
END "Period"
,Amounts
from (
SELECT  A.DB,A.Sub,A.acct,A.FiscYr,A.CpnyID
, sum(A.PtdBal00) "PtdBal00" 
,sum(A.PtdBal01) "PtdBal01"
,sum(A.PtdBal02) "PtdBal02"
,sum(A.PtdBal03) "PtdBal03"
,sum(A.PtdBal04) "PtdBal04"
,sum(A.PtdBal05) "PtdBal05"
,sum(A.PtdBal06) "PtdBal06"
,sum(A.PtdBal07) "PtdBal07"
,sum(A.PtdBal08) "PtdBal08"
,sum(A.PtdBal09) "PtdBal09"
,sum(A.PtdBal10) "PtdBal10"
,sum(A.PtdBal11) "PtdBal11"
FROM vz_Finance_Budget A
Group by   A.DB,A.Sub,A.acct,A.FiscYr,A.CpnyID
)xx
UNPIVOT (Amounts for Period in ('+@cols+')) unpiv;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Edit2:
Thank you for all the suggestions. I decided that the limiting factor is microsoft query itself. Plus microsoft query should be replaced with something newer (I think). Instead of configuring my server to allow openrowset or OPENQuery. I will look into microsoft query replacement. 
not sure if this is the right way to go. but I will update here. thanks.

Edit3: Trying this blog now: http://blogs.office.com/2010/06/07/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba/  I will update when I complete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using this blog below
http://blogs.office.com/2010/06/07/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba/

basically in excel, when you click data tab - From other sources - instead of "from microsoft query". I select "from SQL server". With "from SQL Server". I have the option in the "Connection properties - definition" to select the command type to SQL (instead of table)

the blog explains this with screenshot... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can have explicit `JOIN` in `Microsoft Query`

[Description of the usage of joins in Microsoft Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/136699)

```
SELECT ....
FROM tbl1, tbl2
WHERE tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
```

**Update**

If you want to have the result set in Excel, You can use `OPENROWSET` to export the data from SQL Server to Excel.

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT name, address, Amount, BudgetAmt FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT g.name, g.address, g.Amount, b.BudgetAmt FROM gTable g
LEFT JOIN #tmpBudget b ON b.NameID = g.NameID
```

As you just mentioned earlier, you need to save your proc result into a temp table first

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #tmpBudget
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI'
                ,'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                ,'EXEC SP_Budget')
```

Comment: correct. I just need a way to simulate my complex logic and present it like a simple table, then Microsoft Query can pick it up. problem is my complex logic need to be a stored procedure, and I just don't know how to get away without stored procedure. And the reason it has to be a Stored procedure is because, it is only way I know how to get my Dynamic UNPIVOT SQL. If I am not mistaken Function cannot allow exec statement. And in my Dynamic UNPIVOT SQL , I have exec sp_executeSQL .. If only I can find another way then I can use a function instead.