# convert SQL output in databricks from long to wide

Tags: sql, wide-format-data

I have a very simple outcome in databricks that has 80M lines of data because there is a separate line for each PIN.   The data is a listing by PIN with columns "pin", "device category", "device name".   a PIN may have 1 or 3 or n devices and there are two possible device categories.   I need to convert this from long to wide so I can have a distinct PIN with columns with the devices so I can use this to cluster.  All the examples have distinct column names to plug in to the pivot IN statement.   This doesn't need to be fancy where the column names change dynamically - they can just be "device1", "device2", "device3", "device4", etc.    Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

note:  the column names "device1" etc do not need to be "devicen..".   For example R just assigns column names.   This what I am looking for here.  However many columns are needed it just assigns them

Start at this - long

| machid | device |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 456 | B |
| 123 | C |

Needs to be this - wide

| machid | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | C |  |  |
| 456 | B |  |  |  |

Comment: Hi- please update your question with sample data, the result you are trying to achieve and the SQL you’ve managed to write so far- all as editable text, formatted appropriately

Comment: Thank you for the response.   My data is proprietary.    How do I submit example data that can be helpful?  Sorry I don’t know how to!

Comment: You type the example data into your question and format it as tables (https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables). Minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: entered updated above, thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: That’s pictures, not editable text as requested - so no-one  can copy your data if they want to try out a solution

Comment: I updated it for you!

Comment: This is a data PIVOT which requires 3 fields. Possibly calculate field for column headings using ROW_NUMBER OVER(). Do research and when you have code with issue, post question or edit this one.

Comment: PIVOT can get quite complicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585094/sql-server-pivots-displaying-row-values-to-column-headers

Comment: Yes I did the research.  It appears from the response here that SQL is not capable of doing what R or Python can do quite easily with a single line

Comment: I use Access connected to SQLServer and Access SQL can PIVOT quite easily. I am trying to figure out how to get same dynamic output with pass-through query and it is not going well.

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax that worked for me. I tested in Access pass-through query and in SSMS. I tried testing at SQLFiddle.com so I could provide a demo but get error "Must declare the scalar variable "@cols"." However, not seeing STUFF() nor STRING_AGG() nor QUOTENAME() functions in Databricks documentation and not finding equivalents.

```
SET NoCount ON;

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH GS AS(
SELECT machid, device, 
Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY machid ORDER BY machid, device) As GrpSeq 
FROM table1)

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(G) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GrpSeq AS G FROM GS) AS G
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT machid, device, 
             Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY machid ORDER BY machid, device) As GrpSeq FROM table1) AS Q
       PIVOT(Min(device) FOR GrpSeq IN(' + @cols + ')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

And this version also worked:

```sql
SET NoCount ON;

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH GS AS(
SELECT machid, device, QUOTENAME(Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY machid ORDER BY machid, device)) As GrpSeq FROM Table1),
DS AS
(SELECT DISTINCT GrpSeq FROM GS),
CS AS
(SELECT STRING_AGG(GrpSeq,',') AS G FROM DS)

SELECT @cols = G FROM CS

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT machid, device, Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY machid ORDER BY machid, device) As GrpSeq FROM Table1) AS Q
            PIVOT(Min(machid) FOR GrpSeq IN(' + @cols + ')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

In either, if I try concatenating any text to Row_Number expression, it fails.