# How can I see non-standard characters in MS Access (Stored in SQL Server) correctly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I currently store my string fields in SQL Server as `varchar(x)`.  The Database stores records from across the globe, but non standard characters, such as 'glyphics from Asia or Cyrillic Script/Azbuka from Russia appear as '?????????????' question marks.

How can I prevent this from happening and what are the ramifications of changing SQL Server to handle such input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Unicode support you have to use :

```
nvarchar(x)
```

**nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)**

`nchar [ ( n ) ]` - Fixed-length Unicode character data of n characters. n must be a value from 1 through 4,000.

`nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]` - Variable-length Unicode character data. ncan be a value from 1 through 4,000.

Also, you can refer:

[What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

[varchar vs nvarchar performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Comment: Thanks, should there be any performance difference, comparing to varchar of the same character length.

Comment: For Unicode support you have to use nvarchar. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366/varchar-vs-nvarchar-performance