# What is the difference between nvarchar of different number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nvarchar

I only started learning SQL less than a week ago and I have noticed in SQL Server, string can be of type `nvarchar(5)` or `nvarchar(20)` or any other number. I was just wondering what is the difference between `nvarchar` of different number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the main performance differences between varchar and nvarchar SQL Server data types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366/what-are-the-main-performance-differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar-sql-serve)

Comment: @theinarasu at the least, the question is not about perfromances but language syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a declaratory statement you are referring to.

**By declaratory, this is a method of declaring. MySQL has different rules depending on the context, so it is worth taking the time to know the syntax.**

In SQL, such as MySQL, there are some datatypes that can be of variable length.

What you see is a declaratory statement where NVARCHAR is of different lengths.

```
<DATA TYPE> (<character length>)
 NVARCHAR(5) -- 5 unicode characters long.
 NVARCHAR(20) -- unicode length of 20 characters
```

If you do not specify a length these types of data will be one character length. So that is why the standard allows for parentheses declarations.

Examples of syntax differences:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(5);

SELECT CAST(<some_column> AS NVARCHAR(20)
FROM <some_table>

CREATE TABLE <schema_name>.<table_name>
( firstColumn NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, secondColumn INT not null)
```

Like many languages, unless there is a constraint to prevent overflowing input, any insertion of a character greater than the length gets `TRUNCATED`...or cut off to fit inside the column.

Answer (score 1):

The number represents the content length. In a column or variable that is defined as `nvarchar(5)` you can put a 5 characters long unicode string. In a column or variable that is defined as `nvarchar(20)` you can put a 20 characters long unicode string.
This is all very basic stuff in sql, I suggest reading a good sql tutorial and come here with questions that are a little bit more advanced.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on a good sql book? and also, when I specify a nvarchar(5) I can still insert string length that is greater than 5, is this suppose to happen? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Not for a book, but you can start with w3schools sql tutorial and move on to more advanced stuff later on. If you try to insert a 20 chars length string into an  `nvarchar(5)` column sql server would raise an error saying "string or binary data would be truncated".